# Search for unread messages in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

I show 3 unread messages in Google Groups.  How do you search for the unread messages? I've looked and can't seem to locate the messages. I have an option to Mark All As Read and if I click on it, the unread messages go away.  However, I have no idea what the messages were. How do I search for the Unread Messages?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a way to filter for unread messages, however [there are hot keys](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/6148722?hl=en) which will take you to the next/previous unread message, `shift+j`/`shift+k`, or `shift+n`/`shift+p`. Not too sure the difference.

It looks like there is possibly [a bug in Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/Apps/i0xZe3wwYeA/aO88G8HdZs0J), though, where it might show an inaccurate count, so there may in fact be no unread messages.